Hugging Face model with large context window
Im looking for a model that accepts input like 50k characters and a prompt answering a question based on that text. Is there something available like that? Not sure how to find it, new to AI.

You can look here. In your case, you should be looking for an LLM with context window greater than 50K. You can find many such LLMs.

